# Boto3: faster S3 Bucket Tag matching possible?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

### Target: Get all S3 buckets tagged with owner=dotslashshawn

Firstly, I'd like to say any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have working code allowing me to do this but there doesn't seem to be a way, unlike with EC2 and RDS resources, that will allow me to pull only buckets where that tag exists. I have to pull all buckets and then loop through each to get their tags, then make the comparison unless I've missed something.

It takes **12 seconds** to do this operation and I'm thinking, there must be a faster way. I'm keeping in mind that it'll only get slower the more buckets that are found.

**`Question: Is this something I could speed up using parallel processing?`**

I have cross account permissions set up because I'm looking in 5 separate accounts for matches.

#### Example Code:

```
accounts = [
    '123', # Account 1
    '456', # Account 2
    '789', # Account 3
    '987', # Account 4
    '654', # Account 5
]
s3_data = []
owner = 'dotslashshawn'
# Loop through roles
for account in accounts:

    # Assume each role

    assumed_role = sts.assume_role(
    RoleArn= f'arn:aws:iam::{account}:role/custom-role',
    RoleSessionName="DotSlashShawnSession"
    )
    # Assign credentials
    assumed_role_credentials = assumed_role['Credentials']

    client = boto3.client('s3',
    aws_access_key_id=assumed_role_credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=assumed_role_credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=assumed_role_credentials['SessionToken'],
    region_name = 'us-east-2',
    )

    # get s3 buckets and filter by tag value
    response = client.list_buckets()


    # # Loop through resources and add to list
    for bucket in response['Buckets']:
        bucket_name = bucket['Name']
        try:
            tagging_response = client.get_bucket_tagging(Bucket=bucket_name)
            for tag in tagging_response['TagSet']:
                tagging_response.update({f'{tag["Key"]}':f'{tag["Value"]}'})

        # Remove TagSet after we extract the tags into the main object.
            tagging_response.pop('TagSet')
            if (tagging_response.get('owner') == f'{owner}') or (tagging_response.get('owner2') == f'{owner}'):
                s3_data.append(tagging_response)
        except Exception as e:
            continue

print(s3_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use parallel processing to execute tasks by using `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

In your code there are several action that can run in parallel, like getting credentials and getting tag of the buckets.

Here is what I would do:

`init_s3_client` is ran in parallel in order to speed up the credentials information. This will create a unique s3 client with proper permission.

Then you can have all your logic of listing buckets and findings tags in another method, `execute_logic` that can also run in parallel.

```
import boto3
import json
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

accounts = [
    '123', # Account 1
    '456', # Account 2
    '789', # Account 3
    '987', # Account 4
    '654', # Account 5
]
s3_data = []
owner = 'dotslashshawn'
s3_client = []


def sts_get_credentials(account):
    client = boto3.client('sts')
    response = client.assume_role(
        RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::{}:role/{}'.format(account, 'custom-role'),
        RoleSessionName='DotSlashShawnSession'
    )
    return response['Credentials']

def init_s3_client(credentials):
    for account in accounts:
        s3_client.append(
            {
                'account': account,
                'client': boto3.client(
                    's3',
                    aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
                    aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
                    aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
                    region_name = 'us-east-2'
                )
            }
        )

def execute_logic(client):

    # get s3 buckets and filter by tag value
    response = client.list_buckets()

    # # Loop through resources and add to list
    for bucket in response['Buckets']:
        bucket_name = bucket['Name']
        try:
            tagging_response = client.get_bucket_tagging(Bucket=bucket_name)
            for tag in tagging_response['TagSet']:
                tagging_response.update({f'{tag["Key"]}':f'{tag["Value"]}'})

        # Remove TagSet after we extract the tags into the main object.
            tagging_response.pop('TagSet')
            if (tagging_response.get('owner') == f'{owner}') or (tagging_response.get('owner2') == f'{owner}'):
                s3_data.append(tagging_response)
        except Exception as e:
            continue

async def non_blocking(executor):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    execute_logic_tasks = []
    s3_init_tasks = []
    results = []
    results_execute_logic_tasks = []

    # Executing get credentials in parallel
    for account in accounts:
        s3_init_tasks.append(loop.run_in_executor(executor, init_s3_client, sts_get_credentials(account)))
    
    if len(s3_init_tasks) > 0:
        completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(s3_init_tasks)
        results_s3_init_tasks = [t.result() for t in completed]
    else:
        results_s3_init_tasks = []
    
    results.append(results_s3_init_tasks)

    # Executing get buckets in parallel
    for account in accounts:
        execute_logic_tasks.append(loop.run_in_executor(executor, execute_logic, s3_client[account]['client']))

    if len(execute_logic_tasks) > 0:
        completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(execute_logic_tasks)
        results_execute_logic_tasks = [t.result() for t in completed]
    else:
        results_execute_logic_tasks = []
    
    results.append(results_execute_logic_tasks)

    return results


if __name__ == "__main__":

    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(
        max_workers=10,
    )
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # async next
    start = timer()

    non_blocking_results = event_loop.run_until_complete(non_blocking(executor))    

    elapsed = (timer() - start)
    logger.debug("Non-blocking took: {}".format(elapsed))
    logger.info(s3_data)
```